# Can't get my <input>-fields to work with the css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style my `<input>` fields, but they won't work with the css.

CSS:

```
input {
border:1px solid #0066BB;
backround-color:#111;
-webkit-appearence:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
```

Comment: Two spelling mistakes `backround-color` should be `background-color` and `-webkit-appearence: none` should be `-webkit-appearance: none`. [Fixing those, it works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GSc89/).

Comment: @DavidThomas you should put that as an answer, you're correct http://jsfiddle.net/TMxtP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give your inputs a class and modify that class in your css.

```
.uniqueInputs{
    border:1px solid #0066BB;
    background-color:#111;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

and for the inputs themselves

```
<input class="uniqueInputs" type="text"><br>
```

Comment: as @David Thomas said before the error is because of a couple of typos. i.e. backround-color:#111; should be background-color. your "solution" will not work because of those typos.

Comment: `<br />` is no more valid than `<br>`; the extra `/` is actually explicitly ignored in HTML parsing. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element and http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag step 6. I will edit your answer to remove this inaccuracy.

Comment: @DavidThomas well it was either that or downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Just correct the spelling mistake of background:

```
input {
border:1px solid #0066BB;
background-color:#111;
-webkit-appearence:none;
}
```

Comment: *And* the mistake in `appearence` (third vowel should be an 'a', not 'e').

Answer (score 0):

just give them a class like :

```
<input type="text" class="inputs"/>

.input{
    border:1px solid #0066BB;
    backround-color:#111;
    -webkit-appearence:none;
}
```

or select them by type

```
<input type="text"/>

input[type=text]{
    border:1px solid #0066BB;
    backround-color:#111;
    -webkit-appearence:none;
}
```

Comment: You've maintained the `appearance` typo for some reason.